# Hadoop 2.2 Installation `.' no such file or directory

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have installed Hadoop and HDFS using this tutorial

```
http://codesfusion.blogspot.com/2013/10/setup-hadoop-2x-220-on-ubuntu.html
```

Everything is fine.

I am also able to create directories and use them using

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp
hadoop fs -mkdir /small
```

I can also say

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

However I am following a tutorial in which the trainer does

```
hadoop fs -mkdir temp
hadoop fs -ls
```

now on my machine when I issue the above command it says

```
ls: `.': No such file or directory
```

In my training video the command hadoop fs -ls works perfectly. Why should I specify the "/"?

Also I am getting this warning in all my commands

```
13/12/28 20:23:52 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

But in my trainers video there is no such warning.

My configuration file is exactly as the tutorial above and I can also see all management UIs at

```
http://abhishek-pc:8042/
http://abhishek-pc:50070/
http://abhishek-pc:8088/
```

So my question is what is wrong with my configuration and why is my system behaving differently than the training video?

Comment: have you formatted your namenode?

Comment: yes. as per tutorial above I did `hdfs namenode -format` after that I created my own directories and also copied local files into HDFS and everything is fine. but I my training video can use URLs like tmp whereas I must use /tmp. training video can also do hdfs://machine:10001/data/tmp but I must do /tmp.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Well, your problem regarding `ls: '.': No such file or directory`' is because, there is no home dir on HDFS for your current user. Try

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/[current login user]
```

Then you will be able to `hadoop fs -ls`

As per this warning `WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable`, please see my answer at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-error-on-centos/19993403#19993403)

Comment: maybe an explanation of why this works would be great; it solved my problem but seems a bit strange.

Comment: Here's a gold badge for you sir, thanks for solving my problem.

Answer (score 6):

First:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user
```

then perform

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/hduser
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved this. Run hadoop fs -ls as hdfs user(not as root user). #su - hdfs.

Comment: Can you pleas expand on the commands that are using, what they mean and what difference it makes to the stated problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar type of problem during tutorial by hadoop form link-

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

when i tried command - `bin/hdfs dfs -put etc/hadoop input` , it says

```
mkdir: `input': No such file or directory
```

then problem solved by adding extra / to input and command should be -

```
bin/hdfs dfs -put etc/hadoop /input
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also happen due to bad carriage return characters. Run `dos2unix' on all your hdfs executable (shell script) and if required all other related shell scripts as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all when you want for the first time to put something in your HDFS you should do this steps

1. `hdfs fs -mkdir -p /user/nameuser(the name of user )`
2. `hdfs fs -put ~/file`

Answer (score -1):

after `hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/[user name]`

do :

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

it's works form me !