# HDFS error put: `input': No such file or directory

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop2

I have installed hadoop 2.6.0 and I'm playing around with it. I'm trying the Pseudo-distributed setup and I'm following the instructions on http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Execution 
I'm stuck at the 5th step i.e. when I run the command

```
  bin/hdfs dfs -put etc/hadoop input
```

I get the below error.

```
15/02/02 00:35:49 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
put: `input': No such file or directory
```

Why am I getting this error? How can I resolve it?

Comment: this issue has answer here, its work and really useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821584/hadoop-2-2-installation-no-such-file-or-directory/20821739#20821739

Answer (score 11):

In addition to what Ashrith wrote
-p can also be added, just in case the directory is not yet created.

```
bin/hadoop fs -mkdir -p /path/to/hdfs/dir
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: -p : Preserves access and modification times, ownership and the permissions. (assuming the permissions can be propagated across filesystems): https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#put

Answer (score 4):

Just put "/" infront of input as it is a directory.

```
./bin/hdfs dfs -put etc/hadoop /input
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the error, because there is no such directory specified in the path. Please take a look at [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241251/hadoop-fs-ls-results-in-no-such-file-or-directory/28260263#28260263) which explains how hadoop interprets relative path's.

Make sure you create the directory first using:

```
bin/hadoop fs -mkdir input
```

and then try to re-execute the command `-put`.

Answer (score 0):

In the above question two parts:

1. Its showing warning thats becuase U must be using 64bit one and Hadoop Native Lib compiled in 32 bit. Its a warning so will no effect on your code.
2. The second is error basically because its not able to put the file inside the input folder. U need to create folder in hadoop using the hadoop mkdir command:

hadoop fs -mkdir /hadoopinput

OR [For new version]

hdfs dfs -mkdir /hadoopinput

**Now U can put file inside the folder:**

hdfs dfs -put /Users/{username}/Desktop/file01 /hadoopinput

**To check the file is copied inside the folder or not use following command:**

hdfs dfs -ls /hadoopinput

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
1. Make your directory in hdfs 
hdfs dfs -mkdir /input_file_name
2. Copy data to hdfs.
hadoop fs -put filename.txt /input_file_name/output_file_name

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors first one is native hadoop library for your platform. This is because you have not installed hadoop winutils for your hadoop version. Check this answer for more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/46382570/6337190
The second error is no such file or directory. This is because you have to specify path correctly. Change directory to your hadoop/bin/ and write commands

To make directory

hdfs dfs -mkdir /input

To put file in directory

hdfs dfs -put /path/to/file.txt /input

To check file in directory

hdfs dfs -ls /input

Answer (score 0):

change the user:owner, if want to write any file from root to hdfs directly

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -chown root:hdfs /user/file --{/file} 
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -chmod -R 775 /user/file
```

Or

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -chown -R hdfs:hadoop /user/file 
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -chmod -R 1777 /user/file
```

then use put command

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -put /root/project/* /file --{/user/file}
```

works for me

```
[root@spark ~]# sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -put /root/project/* /file/
put: `file/': No such file or directory
[root@spark ~]# hdfs dfs -put /root/project/* /file
put: Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="/file":hdfs:hadoop:drwxr-xr-t

[root@spark ~]# sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -chown root:hdfs /file
[root@spark ~]# hdfs dfs -put /root/project/*.csv /file
[root@spark ~]# hdfs dfs -ls /file
```

Found 12 items

```
rw-r--r--   1 root hdfs    4662272 2019-04-28 06:23 /file/StokKs.csv
rw-r--r--   1 root hdfs     302648 2019-04-28 06:23 /file/Stocks.csv
rw-r--r--   1 root hdfs     284628 2019-04-28 06:23 /file/Stocks.csv
rw-r--r--   1 root hdfs     568949 2019-04-28 06:23 /file/Satellite.csv
rw-r--r--   1 root hdfs     579302 2019-04-28 06:23 /file/Stocks.csv
rw-r--r--   1 root hdfs   24805721 2019-04-28 06:23 /file/medical.csv
rw-r--r--   1 root hdfs    5650234 2019-04-28 06:23 /file/bank.csv
rw-r--r--   1 root hdfs    2893092 2019-04-28 06:23 /file/facebook.csv
```