# Hadoop fs -ls throws error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

the problem that I am facing is that when I give this command 
"hadoop fs -ls" , it throws this message , "ls: `.': No such file or directory
".

For reference Output result to my "jps" command is

```
18276 SecondaryNameNode
19684 Jps
17942 NameNode
18566 NodeManager
18441 ResourceManager
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hadoop 2.2 Installation \`.' no such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821584/hadoop-2-2-installation-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241251/hadoop-fs-ls-results-in-no-such-file-or-directory/28260263#28260263

Comment: @cricket_007 yes I tried it... and yes the Duplicate link one that you posted solved my issue... Thanks all...

Answer (score 1):

First you should have a data node running which stores the data otherwise you will not be able to deal with hadoop fs (File System).

Try to stall all services

```
$start-all-sh
$jps
```

Ensure that data node is running and nothing obstacles it

Then try

```
$hadoop fs -ls /
```

Comment: Yep. There was the directory missing... I tried above step and it didn't resolve the error...

Comment: @GauravADubey Did you ensure that the data node is running  and that you formatted the namenode: hadoop namenode -format

Comment: @MosabShaheen Yes I did that. And it completed everything smoothly. The step you mentioned worked once I created the directory using 
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/mysystemname

Comment: @GauravADubey Great. When I setup hadoop there was already a folder under /user/ holding the user name. But it is not mandatory to use that folder you can work on the root directory for testing that's why I wrote: $hadoop fs -ls /

Answer (score 1):

When you don't pass any argument to this `hadoop fs -ls` command, the default hdfs directory it tries to list is `/user/{your_user_name}`

The problem in your case could be that this hdfs directory does not exist.

Try running `hadoop fs -ls /user/` to see which directories are created for which users.

You can also just create your user's hdfs default directory. Running the below command will fix your error:

`hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/$(whoami)`

Comment: This would need to be ran as the `hdfs` or `hadoop` user, not the current logged in user, depending on installation process

Comment: Hi.. Yes the problem was that there was no directory for hadoop and so created it using -mkdir statement. After that things started working...

Comment: Alsthough I think stop-all.sh or stopping hdfs and yarn individually was needed else it was throwing some issue.